# jquery - iterate over checkboxes and determine if checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I want to iterate over checkboxes div and determine if checkbox1,checkbox2,checkbox3 are checked

```
    // iterate over checkboxes
    $('#register_students').click(function() { 
        $("div.checkboxes").each(function() {           
            var student = $(this).attr('data');             
            var checkbox1 = ??? 
            var checkbox2 = ???
            var checkbox3 = ???
        });     
        return false;
    });




<td>
<div class='checkboxes' data=8255>
<INPUT type="checkbox"  value="36" class="checkbox1">
<INPUT type="checkbox"  value="14" class="checkbox2">
</div>
</td>

<td>
<div class='checkboxes' data=8244>
<INPUT type="checkbox"  value="36" class="checkbox1">
<INPUT type="checkbox"  value="14" class="checkbox2">
<INPUT type="checkbox"  value="14" class="checkbox3">
</div>
</td>
```

Comment: Are there always 3 checkboxes? In your first html block, there's only 2.

Comment: @GenericTypeTea: Good question. @roger rover: Is the need to iterate through the checkboxes because there may be a variable number of checkboxes in a div?

Comment: may be zero or more checkboxes. (typically 3-25)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're interating over the `divs` containing the checkboxes, so you need to `find` your checkboxes.

(You should also probably cache `$(this)` to avoid multiple calls):

```
    $("div.checkboxes").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);           
        var student = $this.attr('data');             
        var checkbox1 = $this.find('input.checkbox1').is(':checked'); 
        var checkbox2 = $this.find('input.checkbox2').is(':checked'); 
        var checkbox3 = $this.find('input.checkbox3').is(':checked'); 
    });     
    return false;
```

The three checkbox lines will each return a boolean indicating whther the checkbox in the current div is checked.

Comment: I think you mean `:checked`, not `.checked`.

Comment: Ooops! Good spot. One typo + 2 copy/pastes

Comment: check your brackets...
var checkbox1 = $(this).find('input.checkbox1').is(':checked');

Answer (score 5):

Use this.

```
$(this).is(':checked')
```

returns `true` or `false` . Like,

```
$('#register_students').click(function() {
    $("div.checkboxes").each(function(index1) {
        var student = $(this).attr('data');
        cb = [];           
        $('input[type=checkbox]',this).each(function(index2, Element){
           cb[index2] = $(Element).is(':checked');
        });
        // use 'cb' and 'student' as you want. 3 checkbox value are as cb[0], cb[1], cb[2]
    });     
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I'd rather use the selector than comparing values. But this is just a matter or preference ;-)

Comment: `$(this)` will refer to the `div` itself, right? We will need a selector for the checkboxes within the `div`.

Comment: @DLH, as detailed in my answer below

Comment: @Wiseman: Indeed. Now that yours is corrected, I've upvoted it. :)

Comment: @DLH: I intended to give directions, so the answer was short and sweet. Updated, after reading the discussions. Thanks dood.

Comment: Personall,  I would prefer 'input:checkbox' instead of 'input[type=checkbox]'

Comment: Well it does the same thing internally. In fact, i am when you say [type=checkbox], you are indicating it specifically, to look in attribute 'type' and not go for a match against any other. I would say, its my personal thought.

Answer (score 3):

Used the `:checked` selector.

http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

EDIT:

And for such examples I would try it on **http://jsfiddle.net/**... helps a lot!